# R: How to find/replace and then automatically execute code?

Tags: r, loops, gsub

I have a some R code saved in a file (test_code.R).

```
ABC_common <- big_fread1("E:/folder/ABC_annotation.text", 
every_nlines=5e5,sep="\t")

makeGRangesFromDataFrame(ABC_common,seqinfo=NULL)

ABC_shared <- ABC_unique[!rownames(ABC_unique) %in% CBL_shared$column1,]
```

I also have a single dataframe of names

```
goal_shared <- read.delim("E:/goal_shared.txt", header=FALSE)

     V1
1    name1
2    name2
3    name3
4    name4
```

I would like to substitute a word  in the code ("ABC" in the example code) with each "name" in the dataframe. For instance, substitute "name1" for "ABC". Then, automatically execute the code. Then, in parallel, substitute "name2" for "ABC", then automatically execute the code. And so on, down the list of "names" in the dataframe.

So far, I have used gsub_file to successfully replace "ABC" with "name1".

```
gsub_file("test_code.R", "ABC", "name1", fixed=TRUE)
```

However, I am not sure how to proceed with:

1. recursively doing this down the list of "names" in the dataframe
2. automatically executing the code after each substitution
3. performing each substitution and execution in parallel (running Windows).

Any help would be greatly appreciated

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Hard to give an exact answer without a fully reproducible question, but here's an attempt. `gsub_file` changes the target file in place, so in the code you've written, the substitution will only work once. A better solution would be to copy your template file into a temporary connection, and then modify that:

```
for (i in goal_shared$V1) {

  f <- tempfile() # create a temp file
  template <- readLines('test_code.R') # read your template file
  writeLines(template, f) # write the template code into a temp connection
  gsub_file(f, "ABC", i, fixed=TRUE) # rewrite the temp file
  source(f) # run the temp file

}
```

Comment: Thank you. How would I set this up to run in parallel?